# Listview row checked when I scroll pass 7th objects

Tags: android, listview

I am working on my listview where I disable the button of the row after I click on it. My issue is when I click on button1 it will disable other buttons in other rows too which is the 9th object. The following is my code for getView method.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        Typeface face_02 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "customfont/grb.otf");

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.Boothname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Boothname);
            holder.buttonVote = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonvote);
            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        BoothClassFunAward product = productList.get(position);

        holder.buttonVote.setTypeface(face_02);
        holder.Boothname.setText(product.getBoothName());
        holder.Boothname.setTypeface(face_02); //setFontsize
        //holder.buttonVote.setTypeface(face_02); //setFontsize

        for(int i = 0; i<votedList.size(); i++) {
            if (votedList.get(i).getBoothName().equals(product.getBoothName())) {
                holder.buttonVote.setTypeface(face_02);
                holder.buttonVote.setEnabled(false);
                holder.buttonVote.setText("Completed");
            }
        }

        holder.buttonVote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String Boothdata=  holder.Boothname.getText().toString();
                //final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                //prefs.edit().putString("boothdata", Boothdata).commit();

                //Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, ProgramActivity.class);
                //context.startActivity(intent2);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProgramActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("storedata", Boothdata);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
    });
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The rest of buttons needs to be enabled again, add this line:

```
    holder.buttonVote.setEnabled(true);

    for(int i = 0; i<votedList.size(); i++) {
        if (votedList.get(i).getBoothName().equals(product.getBoothName())) {
            holder.buttonVote.setTypeface(face_02);
            holder.buttonVote.setEnabled(false);
            holder.buttonVote.setText("Completed");
        } 
    }
```